# Forward declaration of a function typedef in C

Tags: c

I have a nagging suspicion that this has been asked before, but I'm not finding it...

Suppose I have a typedef for function A that takes a pointer to a function with typedef B, which in turn takes a function of typedef A.  If one of these was a struct, I know how I would handle the forward declaration, but for functions I don't know the syntax.  Is there one?

I want to be able to do:

```
typedef void (*function_A_t)(function_B_t f_B);
typedef void (*function_B_t)(function_A_t f_A);
```

Any hints?  Even better, a reference?  Incidentally this actually just happened for me, but I was able to fix it another way, although this would actually smoother (better decoupling, less chance of next guy messing it up) if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by taking advantage of the fact that C specifies that a function declaration with no arguments means it takes an indeterminate number of arguments.

So you could do it as follows:

```
typedef void (*function_A_t)(void (*)());
typedef void (*function_B_t)(function_A_t f_A);
```

Which allows the following to compile:

```
void A(function_B_t b)
{
    b(A);
}

void B(function_A_t a)
{
    a(B);
}

int main()
{
    function_A_t a = A;
    function_B_t b = B;
    a(B);
    b(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Section 6.7.6.3p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states the following regarding the compatibility of function types:

> For two  function  types  to  be  compatible,  both  shall  specify
> compatible  return  types. Moreover,  the  parameter  type  lists,  if
> both  are  present,  shall  agree  in  the  number  of parameters  and
> in  use  of  the  ellipsis  terminator;  corresponding  parameters
> shall  have compatible types.  **If one type has a parameter type list
> and the other type is specified by a function  declarator  that  is
> not  part  of  a  function  definition  and  that  contains  an  empty
> identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis
> terminator and the type of each parameter  shall  be  compatible  with
> the  type  that  results  from  the  application  of  the default
> argument promotions.**  If one type has a parameter type list and the
> other type is specified by a function definition that contains a
> (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree  in  the  number
> of  parameters,  and  the  type  of  each  prototype  parameter  shall
> be compatible  with  the  type  that  results  from  the  application
> of  the  default  argument promotions  to  the  type  of  the
> corresponding  identifier.   (In  the  determination  of  type
> compatibility  and  of  a  composite  type,  each  parameter  declared
> with  function  or  array type is taken as having the adjusted type
> and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the
> unqualified version of its declared type.)

The part in bold above specifies that `void (*)()` is compatible with `void (*)(function_B_t)`

Comment: To which C versions does this pertain?

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that this will work, but reduce the compiler's ability to check the parameter lists at the point of call?

Comment: @Basya The standard quote above is from C11, but it applies to C89 and later.  And yes this will allow any function pointer that has a `void` return type as a parameter.  It's not ideal but the best we can do.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been programming C for years and this was new to me...

Comment: @dbush This is great!  Special thank you for the reference to the standard.